# How to run whole for loop (forever loop) to get the whole table records ?

Tags: python

How to run whole for loop to get the whole table records, rather than for loop forever just get first record only

Code:

```
import time
import urllib2
from bs4  import BeautifulSoup

while True:
  contenturl = "http://www.bank.gov.ua/control/en/curmetal/detail/currency?period=daily"
  soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(contenturl).read())

  table = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'content'})

  rows = table.findAll('tr')
  for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    if 'cell_c' in cols[0]['class']:
        # currency row
        digital_code, letter_code, units, name, rate = [c.text for c in cols]
        print digital_code, letter_code, units, name, rate
        break
        time.sleep(1)
```

output from code: (repeat for loop just first data)

```
036 AUD 100 Australian Dollar 1207.1332  
036 AUD 100 Australian Dollar 1207.1332
036 AUD 100 Australian Dollar 1207.1332
036 AUD 100 Australian Dollar 1207.1332
036 AUD 100 Australian Dollar 1207.1332
036 AUD 100 Australian Dollar 1207.1332
036 AUD 100 Australian Dollar 1207.1332
036 AUD 100 Australian Dollar 1207.1332
036 AUD 100 Australian Dollar 1207.1332
```

Expected Output: (repeat for loop for whole data)

```
036 AUD 100 Australian Dollar 1207.1332
944 AZN 100 Azerbaijanian Manat 1651.6929
974 BYR 10 Belarussian Ruble 0.0125
124 CAD 100 Canadian Dollar 1190.6335
203 CZK 100 Czech Koruna 62.1306
208 DKK 100 Danish Krone 232.5053
978 EUR 100 EURO 1733.4432
348 HUF 1000 Forint 55.2263
352 ISK 100 Iceland Krona 11.2017
440 LTL 100 Lithuanian Litas 502.0399
934 TMT 100 Manat 454.4764
498 MDL 100 Moldovan Leu 94.3694
578 NOK 100 Norwegian Krone 210.5866
826 GBP 100 Pound Sterling 2166.2625
643 RUB 10 Russian ruble 3.5950
960 XDR 100 SDR 1981.8556
702 SGD 100 Singapore Dollar 1040.5446
752 SEK 100 Swedish Krona 189.1724
756 CHF 100 Swiss Franc 1431.7694
398 KZT 100 Tenge 7.1168
949 TRY 100 Turkish Lira 597.4506
840 USD 100 US Dollar 1295.2576
860 UZS 100 Uzbekistan Sum 0.5525
392 JPY 1000 Yen 126.3258
156 CNY 100 Yuan Renminbi 210.7094
985 PLN 100 Zloty 413.8775

036 AUD 100 Australian Dollar 1207.1332
944 AZN 100 Azerbaijanian Manat 1651.6929
974 BYR 10 Belarussian Ruble 0.0125
124 CAD 100 Canadian Dollar 1190.6335
203 CZK 100 Czech Koruna 62.1306
208 DKK 100 Danish Krone 232.5053
978 EUR 100 EURO 1733.4432
348 HUF 1000 Forint 55.2263
352 ISK 100 Iceland Krona 11.2017
440 LTL 100 Lithuanian Litas 502.0399
934 TMT 100 Manat 454.4764
498 MDL 100 Moldovan Leu 94.3694
578 NOK 100 Norwegian Krone 210.5866
826 GBP 100 Pound Sterling 2166.2625
643 RUB 10 Russian ruble 3.5950
960 XDR 100 SDR 1981.8556
702 SGD 100 Singapore Dollar 1040.5446
752 SEK 100 Swedish Krona 189.1724
756 CHF 100 Swiss Franc 1431.7694
398 KZT 100 Tenge 7.1168
949 TRY 100 Turkish Lira 597.4506
840 USD 100 US Dollar 1295.2576
860 UZS 100 Uzbekistan Sum 0.5525
392 JPY 1000 Yen 126.3258
156 CNY 100 Yuan Renminbi 210.7094
985 PLN 100 Zloty 413.8775
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why exactly are you in that `while`loop?

```
contenturl = "http://www.bank.gov.ua/control/en/curmetal/detail/currency?period=daily"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(contenturl).read())
table = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'content'})
rows = table.findAll('tr')
for row in rows:
    print row.text.split()
```

Comment: since i want to repeat get the data, and they will changing afterward.

Comment: Okay... hm. Maybe you want to keep a log of it. Consider appending to a log file per iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: but i want to display whole table in every 1 sec, you code seem have some problem, but anyway, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are `break`ing after finding the first currency row. This is breaking out of the `for` loop that is going through all the rows, and the repeated lines you are seeing come from the `while` loop, which is set to loop forever because the condition is always `True`.

Comment: actually i want to load whole table every for loop, and do this for loop forever for updating the records, thanks !

Comment: That's fine, and `while True` will let you do this forever. But having `break` in your for loop is why you're not seeing all the rows. You're telling it to break out of the loop after the first one you find.